# react.js State is empty although using useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem checking the length of my state although I use axios to get data.
here is what I've done so far.

code:

```
const getAllBanners = async () => {
    res = await axios.get(`/admin_return_banner_positions/`).then((res) => {
      setBanners(res.data.result)
    })
  }

  // HANDLING USEEFFECT
  useEffect(() => {
    getAllBanners()
  }, [])


{getBanners.hits.total.value > 0 ? <>
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th style={{ fontSize: "18px" }}>cat</th>
                        <th><span style={{ fontSize: "18px" }}>up</span><hr /><span> name</span></th>
                        <th style={{ fontSize: "18px" }}>number</th>
                        <th><span style={{ fontSize: "18px" }}>down</span><hr /><span>name2</span></th>
                        <th style={{ fontSize: "18px" }}>number</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead> <> : null}
```

error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'total')
style={{ direction: "rtl", textAlign: "center" }}
  738 | >
> 739 |   {getBanners.hits.total.value > 0 ? <>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `getBanners` state has been initialised with some default value. That value might not be having nested properties up to `total`.

You are probably better off using optional chaining in such scenarios -

```js
const BannerComponent = () => {
  const [getBanners, setBanners] = useState();

  const getAllBanners = async () => {
    await axios.get(`/admin_return_banner_positions/`).then((res) => {
      setBanners(res.data.result)
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllBanners()
  }, []);

  if (getBanners?.hits?.total?.value > 0) { // <---- optional chaining
     return (
       <>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th style={{ fontSize: "18px" }}>cat</th>
               <th><span style={{ fontSize: "18px" }}>up</span><hr /><span> name</span></th>
               <th style={{ fontSize: "18px" }}>number</th>
               <th><span style={{ fontSize: "18px" }}>down</span><hr /><span>name2</span></th>
               <th style={{ fontSize: "18px" }}>number</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
      <>
    );
  }
  return null;
}
```

**NOTE**

- I have formatted the code a little bit to understand it better.
- If you are not aware of optional chaining, this can give you a brief introduction --> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)